# Power Method to Find all Eigenvalues without Shifting

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gershgorin-sets

If a given matrix $A$ is known to have three different and real eigenvalues $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ and we know that they are near $-2$, $2$ and $10$ respectively (using [Gershgorin's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) circle theorem), how would we use the power method to find the value of all the eigenvalues **without** resorting to "shifting" the power method?

In the event that there are multiple ways of doing this, what would be the simplest way using the Power Method?

Comment: If we must use the power method, what other tweaks on the power method are "legal" in the context of this question?